# Ethereum Wallet, No TX Confirms, How to adjust gas price

Tags: transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I run a full node on the ethereum wallet 9.3, have attempted to tx's in the past 3 days with no confirmations and Gas limit used 151,458, but how can I adjust the gas price manually, currently at 14.

Answer (score 1):

Resubmit the transaction with the same `nonce` field, but with higher gas price. MyEtherWallet can do it for you. Or `geth` if you want low level UI